# `output_buffer_dac_time` too slow

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyaudio

I'm playing a synthesized sine with pyaudio using the callback API.

I count the number of frames I've already returned from the callback and divide that number by the frame-rate to get the number of seconds that I've played so far.

Also, I subtract the current `output_buffer_dac_time` from the `output_buffer_dac_time` I got with the very first callback invocation.

I would expect the two to be equal. This is not the case. `output_buffer_dac_time`  is running slow. The difference is small but continously increasing (around 50 microseconds for each second of playback).

Am I doing something wrong or  is this an artefact of the built-in laptop soundcard?

Comment: Code showing how you were doing this is critical for answering this question.